# quick parsing of csv-like file

Tags: python, csv, file-io

The file type I need to read in has the following structure: One line header, then tab separated entries line by line as follows:

```
Date    Timestamp    Identifier    Value
```

File size is around 2MB and for each identifier there are around 200 values in it (around 600k lines). It is possible to read this file in with pythons csv reader and to extract the wanted Identifier columns. As I have several sets of these files, reading in feels quite slow:

```
import csv
def read_file(fhandle, identifiers):
    #identifiers = [identifier1, identifier2, ...]
    #dialect from csvr.sniffer()
    csvr = csv.reader(fhandle, dialect) 
    data = []
    EOF = False            
    while not EOF:
        try:
            row=csvr.next()                        
            if row[2] in identifiers:
                data.append(tuple(row[1:]))
        except StopIteration:
            EOF = True
    fhandle.close()
    sorted(data, keyfunc) #keyfunc = lambda x: (x[1],x[0])
    return data
```

I started trying to speed it up with this function (currently only reads one identifier for testing). It uses regular expressions in order to only parse the lines that contain wanted information. Also it adds to an array instead of appending to a list, which I found to be faster in the past (for large data sets).

```
import re
import numpy as np
def power_read(fhandle, identifier):
    findme = '(?<=%s\W)[0-9.]+' %identifier       
    m = re.compile(findme)
    result = np.zeros(10000)
    cnt = 0
    EOF = False
    while not EOF:
        try: 
            ln = fhandle.next()
            found = re.search(m, ln)
            if found:
                result[cnt] = float(found.group(0))
                cnt += 1
        except StopIteration: 
            EOF=True
            fhandle.close()
    return result[0:cnt]
```

This works, but is not really faster. What else could I tweak?

Comment: Have you tried `numpy.loadtxt()` or `numpy.genfromtxt()`?

Comment: I have just tried `loadtxt` and `genfromtxt`. I could not use `loadtxt()` because there apparently are some missing values, so I switched to `genfromtxt()`. VERY slow.

Comment: Another answer suggests that `pandas.read_csv()` is fast: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7463/fastest-python-library-to-read-a-csv-file

Comment: sadly, I do not have access to pandas on my work PC, so I cannot test that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**short answer:**

`csv reader` and `haraprasadj` (see answer below) are almost identical in speed.

**Long answer:**

I tried out all methods suggested, being `numpy.genfromtxt()`, the code haraprasadj suggested, and I tinkered with my `power_read()` function as follows:

```
def power_read(fhandle, identifiers):
    findme = '(?<=%s\W)[0-9.]+' %identifiers[0]       
    result = np.zeros(10000)
    cnt = 0
    ALL = fhandle.read()
    fhandle.close()
    found = re.findall(findme, ALL, flags=re.S)
    for f in found:
        result[cnt] = float(f)
    return result[0:cnt]
```

Why that change? I figured out, that line wise investigation apparently is taking much longer. Questions version is 18s combined for 10 runs, while the version above is only 6s.

```
numpy.genfromtxt(fhandle, delimiter='\t', 
    dtype={'names':('Time', 'Identifier', 'Value'), 
           'formats':('datetime64[ns]', 'S50', 'f8')})
```

in the same setting uses about 41 seconds and disqualified itself.

Next, I evaluated the average over 50 runs and the outcome is as follows:

- new `power_read`: 0.582 s
- `haraprasadj`: 1.033 s
- `readfile`: 1.081 s

While the `re` solution looks like the winner at this moment, it still does not read out several Identifiers at once. also, csv reads timestamps already. I will investigate now how several keywords can be handled and how it affects execution time. Also, with the full read in one has to always keep memory limitations in mind.

Next step with the `power_read()` function was, that I added some more functionality, including timestamp extraction and support of multiple keywords, returning a handy dictionary:

```
def power_read(fhandle, identifiers):
    ALL = fhandle.read()
    fhandle.close()
    result = {}
    for i in identifiers:
        findme = ('(?P<timestamp>\d+-\d+-\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+.[\d\+]+)\W%s\W(?P<value>[\d.]+)' %i)
        res = np.empty(shape=(10000, 2), dtype=[('time','datetime64[ns]'), ('value','f4')])
        cnt = 0
        found = re.findall(findme, ALL, flags=re.S)
        for f in found:
            res[cnt] = np.array(f, dtype=[('time','datetime64[ns]'), ('value','f4')])
        result[i] = res[0:cnt,:]
    return result
```

I tested with 1 keyword and 3 keywords:

- `read_file` 1kword=1.1s      3kword=1.1s
- `haraprasadj` 1kword=1.0s     3kword=1.1s
- `power_read` 1kword=1.4s     3kword=4.2s

to summarize, unless one only aims to extract just one value csv reader and haraprasadj's method seem superior. Typecasting did not happen for the top two methods as of yet, though. Someone has a good idea how to typecast the results efficiently? To investigate, I changed the methods as follows and called with three keywords:

```
def read_file(fhandle, identifiers, dialect):
    csvr = csv.reader(fhandle, dialect) 
    data = []
    EOF = False            
    while not EOF:
        try:
            row=csvr.next()                        
            if row[2] in identifiers:
                data.append(tuple(row[1:-1]))
        except StopIteration:
            EOF = True
    fhandle.close()
    data = np.array(data, dtype=None)
    time = data[:,0]
    ids = data[:,1]
    value = data[:,2]
    res = {}
    for i in identifiers:
        msk = np.where(ids==i, True, False)
        res[i] = np.array(zip(time[msk], value[msk]), dtype=[('time','datetime64[us]'), ('value','f8')])
    return res
```

and the second function, optimized for the exact data that I deal with:

```
def haraprasadj(fhandle, identifiers):
    data = [line.strip().split('\t')[1:] for line in fhandle.readlines()]
    fhandle.close()
    result = np.array(filter(lambda x:x[1] in identifiers, data))
    time =result[:,0]
    ids = result[:,1]
    value = result[:,2]
    res = {}
    for i in identifiers:
        msk = np.where(ids==i, True, False)
        res[i] = np.array(zip(time[msk], value[msk]), dtype=[('time','datetime64[us]'), ('value','f8')])
    return res
```

It turns out, that both approaches are about same speed (at least for my test file size):

- `read_file()` 1.12 s
- `haraprasadj` 1.06 s

Comparison with previous results indicates that typecasting only takes an insignificant amount of time, which was surprising to me.
Remaining difference is that `haraprasadj` takes more memory, which might be important for some applications. For sake of readability, I will go with my original read_file(), for now and start having a look into parallel computing.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar requirement and I did something like:

```
data = [line.strip('\n').split(',') for line in open('test.txt','r').readlines()]
identifiers = ['2069784', '2640650']
filteredData = filter(lambda x:x[2] in identifiers, data)
```

Tried timing it now and for a text file of size 52 MB (64 columns, 60897 rows) it takes under 3 seconds to fetch required rows. The result has 308 rows.

Please note that my file is comma-separated so splitting by comma. Also I use a Windows 7 machine with 8GB RAM.

Also, can you please share your code's performance details. I am curious to know which approach I should take going forward.